# webSphere Application server stuck at Starting

Tags: java, websphere

I'm using WebSphere 8.5.5.8. In eclipse, I have WebSphere V8.5. When I start the server it gets stuck at 100%. Although it prints

> WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business

but it does not completely start and times out. I have tried increasing timeout but it doesn't help.

I do not get any exceptions and I couldn't find any exception in logs as well.

And when it times out it keeps stopping as well and in the end, I have to use task manager to stop it by force.

Within eclipse, if I try to test the connection I get

> ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host localhost at port 8881.

when it's stopping I can access the admin console as well.

Comment: I doubt that anybody will be able to help you given this input. Beyond that, websphere is a commercial product, so my advice would be: contact the IBM support.

Comment: And just to be sure: you are starting websphere, and you want it to run YOUR application? Or are you talking about a plain vanilla websphere that doesnt come with any application that you added to it?!

Comment: yes, I want it to run my app. I haven't published my app yet. I will try to contact IBM support as well

Comment: The issue is likely a communication issue between eclipse and WebSphere Application Server.  You say you are using eclipse to control WebSphere Application Server, have you tried running WebSphere Application server from the command line?  And if you are running WebSphere Application Server on Windows, and there is a Windows Service running it you should disable that too.   Then once the SystemOut.log has open for e-business try accessing the administrative console or even running from the same command line prompt that you started it with run serverStatus.bat -all